# On android with kotlin the "_uiState.update { current -> current.copy(cart = cartRepository.getCart()) }" is not updating the page

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, composable

This is the AppViewModel

```
data class ApplicationUiState(
    val cart: Cart = Cart(),
    val loading: Boolean = false,
)

class ApplicationViewModel(private val cartRepository: CartRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(ApplicationUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<ApplicationUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        refreshCart()
    }

    fun refreshCart() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            _uiState.update { current -> current.copy(cart = cartRepository.getCart()) }
        }
    }
}
```

on the App composable I have this line

```
    fun ApplicationApp(
    viewModel: ApplicationViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory),
) {
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val applicationUiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
```

...

```
applicationUiState.cart.items.forEach { Text(text = it.id) }
```

and in another part I have this button just to refresh the cart

```
 IconButton(
                    onClick = viewModel::getCart,
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Sync, contentDescription = "",
                        tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
```

In another page I have this

```
fun addToCart(item: Item) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            cartRepository.addItemToCart(item)
        } catch (cancellationException: CancellationException) {
            throw cancellationException
        }
    }
}
```

The cartRepository is just an object in a fakeDataSource class

The object receive the update, but for some reason the `_uiState.update { current -> current.copy(cart = cartRepository.getCart()) }` don't update the _uiState and dont trigger the recomposition of the page... (to be true he does 1 single time, if I add more items the uistate never updates)

If I create an loading atribute and force the attribute to change the _uiState updates the page...

the cartRepository.getCart() is different than the previous value for this page, why the page does not update